# Will SLES11 Compiled code work on RHEL6

Tags: c, rhel5

We used to C-compile our software programs and build our packages on CentOS 5 in the past.
This we know works fine to install on RHEL5,6,7 and SLES10,11,12

But know when we are slowly moving away from RHEL5 we need to know if it is possible to build our software on only one distribution? 
Or if we have to build it on each of them (RHEL/SLES)?

We are using dynamical linked codes; and not static linked code.

Can anyone help me with this question?

Regards Tomas Dalebjörk

Answer (score 0):

Your main concern should be library compatibility.  If your SLES11-compiled code relies on more recent versions of the needed libraries -- including glibc -- than RHEL 6 provides, then you're probably in for trouble.  Of course, you could then do it the other way around, and build on RHEL6.  Or if you're trying to get out from under RedHat licensing (and also to do without RH support) then you could consider CentOS 6 for a build platform.

Comment: Yes, my concern is the libraries. But how do I know which of the distribution has the oldest libraries if I don't even know which libraries and versions the code is dependent of?

Comment: You can estimate by the date of the original release.  These are "enterprise" distributions you're talking about, designed for long-term stability.  They don't upgrade to incompatible library versions during the lifetime of the product.  As for which libraries you depend on, it's *your* software.  You built it, so how can you *not* know which libraries it uses?  If needed, consult the RPMs you built (you *do* build RPMs, right?); they can tell you.  At worst, run `ldd` on your binaries.

Comment: Thanks. Ldd is one way to handle it. But it would be more easy if we could skip to compile on the both distributions.